# Ruby two dimensional array: finding an object's coordinates

Tags: ruby, arrays, coordinates

Assume, I have a two dimensional array `A`, and it's stated that somewhere inside it there's an object `my_element`. What's the quickest way to find out its coordinates? I am using Ruby 1.8.6.

Comment: There really is only one way: loop through all slots until you find what you're looking for (see mtyaka's answer). Worst-case, this is `O(m*n)` where `m` and `n` are the number of rows and columns in your array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one way. I'm not sure it's the quickest, though.

```
class Array
  def coordinates(element)
    each_with_index do |subarray, i|
      j = subarray.index(element)
      return i, j if j
    end
    nil
  end
end


array = [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9] ]
array.coordinates(3)     # => [0, 2]
array.coordinates(9)     # => [2, 2]
array.coordinates(42)    # => nil
```

Comment: Elegant implentation of the coordinates method but I wouldn't add it into the Array class because it doesn't really apply to all arrays. Similar to the argument about whether a "sum" method should be added to Array.

Comment: @mikej Yup, totally agree. I added it into the Array class for demonstration purposes only.