# get coordinates of value in 2D array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I want to get the coordinates of every occurrence of an object stored in an array of arrays. If I have an array:

```
array = [["foo", "bar", "lobster"], ["camel", "trombone", "foo"]]
```

and an object `"foo"`, I want to get:

```
[[0,0], [1,2]]
```

The following will do this, but it's elaborate and ugly:

```
array.map
.with_index{
  |row,row_index| row.map.with_index {
    |v,col_index| v=="foo" ? [row_index,col_index] : v
  }
}
.flatten(1).find_all {|x| x.class==Array}
```

Is there a more straightforward way to do this? This was [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754880/ruby-two-dimensional-array-finding-an-objects-coordinates) before, and produced a similarly inelegant solution.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a slightly more elegant solution. I have:

- Used `flat_map` instead of `flatten`ing at the end
- Used `.each_index.select` instead of `.map.with_index` and then having to strip non-arrays at the end, which is really ugly
- Added indentation

```
array.flat_map.with_index {|row, row_idx|
  row.each_index.select{|i| row[i] == 'foo' }.map{|col_idx| [row_idx, col_idx] }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
array = [["foo", "bar", "lobster"], ["camel", "trombone", "foo"],
         ["goat", "car", "hog"], ["foo", "harp", "foo"]]

array.each_with_index.with_object([]) { |(a,i),b|
   a.each_with_index { |s,j| b << [i,j] if s == "foo" } }
   #=> [[0,0], [1,2], [3,0], [3,2]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to work with flat arrays.

```
cycle = array.first.length
#=> 3
array.flatten.to_enum.with_index
.select{|e, i| e == "foo"}
.map{|e, i| i.divmod(cycle)}
#=> [[0, 0], [1, 2]]
```

or

```
cycle = array.first.length
#=> 3
array = array.flatten
array.each_index.select{|i| array[i] == "foo"}.map{|e, i| i.divmod(cycle)}
#=> [[0, 0], [1, 2]]
```